# Permute positions of properties in an array of JSON objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps

So I have a massive array of objects that looks like this:

```
var obj = [
  {longitude: lng1, latitude: lat1},
  {longitude: lng2, latitude: lat2}
]
```

I need a javascript function that allows me to permute the positions of each object's properties within the array like so:

```
var switchedObj = [
  {latitude: lat1, longitude: lng1},
  {latitude: lat2, longitude: lng2}
]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Comment: `permute the positions` - you want to swap the order of longitude and latitude properties? Can I ask, what difference would that make? the two objects would have identical properties. The upshot is, javascript object properties have no concept of "order" as there is no reason to do so

Comment: Having said that, the order of properties (when output by JSON.stringify) can seemingly be controlled - `var switchedObj = obj.map(function(item) {return {latitude:item.latitude, longitude:item.longitude}}); console.log(JSON.stringify(switchedObj));` - you'll see that the output has the properties in the order you want - now tested in Firefox, Chrum, IE and Edge - all behave identically

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX thanks for your answer. I will try it later. The reason why I need it is because certain frameworks want you to define objects in a certain order, otherwise it doesn't work. I know that in general, javascript has no concept of order, but when third party frameworks are involved, it is a different ball game. I hope you understand my point.

Comment: so these third party frameworks must be using JSON strings for their input? you're not just passing  `obj` as an argument to a function? If you are, and the order is "important" to a 3rd party framework, look for a better 3rd party framework :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Assuming that we have values for lng1 , lat1 , lng2 and lat2.

Basically lets say we have this object:

```
var obj = [
{longitude:10,latitude:100},
{longitude:20, latitude:200}
]
```

Then to get the solution you need simple do this. Hope it helps!

```js
var obj = [
{longitude:10,
 latitude:100
},

{longitude:20,
 latitude:200
}
]

var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
var switchedObj = [];
for(var i in obj){
 if(obj[i].hasOwnProperty("longitude") && obj[i].hasOwnProperty("latitude")){
  arr1.push(obj[i]["longitude"]); // 10 and 20
  arr2.push(obj[i]["latitude"]);
 }
}
for(var k = 0; k < obj.length; k++){
      switchedObj.push({
      latitude: arr2[k],
      longitude: arr1[k]
    });
}

console.log(switchedObj);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @HenryDev. It did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the d3.js [permute](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/permute.js) function:

```
var obj = [
  {longitude: 1, latitude: 2},
  {longitude: 3, latitude: 4}
]

var permute = function(object) { 
  var i = Object.keys(object[0]).length; // ["latitude", "longitude"], length = 2
  var switchedObj = new Array(i);

  while (i--) switchedObj[i] = object[i]; // go through obj in reverse order 
                                          // and assign values to new obj
  return switchedObj;
};

permute(obj); 
// => [
//  {latitude: 2, longitude: 1},
//  {latitude: 4, longitude: 3}
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a for loop that returns an object with the keys in whatever order you want.  This is prime for a map, as shown below.  Unfortunately, there is no requirement in the JS spec that object's properties are kept in the same order.  In practice, they usually do.  But I wouldn't rely on this.

```
var switchedObj = obj.map(coords => 
  ({latitude: coords.latitude, longitude: coords.longitude})
);
```

Edit:  For people using older versions of JavaScript:

```
var switchedObj = obj.map(function(coords) {
  return {
    latitude: coords.latitude,
    longitude: coords.longitude,
  };
});
```